# Does Angular 2 only work with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, node.js, angular

Does Angular 2 only work with NodeJS? I read tutorial on using Angular 2 with Visual Studio 2015

http://www.mithunvp.com/angular-2-in-asp-net-5-typescript-visual-studio-2015/

But even that tutorial uses Package.json and other nodeJS related files. Does this mean Angular 2 can only be used with Node?

If not, does anybody have a proper tutorial link with Angular 2 using Asp.Net without using any kind of Node behind the scenes.

Comment: Questions for external resources (books, libraries, tutorials, ...) are discourgaged on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 doesn't need Node.js at all. You can use Angular2 with plain JavaScript and also with Dart which is not related to Node.js. You also can serve Angular applications with any server.

Answer (score 0):

This is not at all true. `Node's NPM(Node Package Manager)` provides `angular2's` required packages. 
`NPM` is popular for `angular2` because angular team has chosen `NPM` over `bower`(not sure though).
I personally don't use `NODE.js` or `NPM` and still work with `Angular2` .
As of now I use **`CDN`** for **`Angualr2`**'s reference.

Comment: FYI... you must have seen many `plunker demo` here somewhere for `angular2`. Did you see `node.js` in there? No... So answer is **`NO`**.